# Memory leak when returning an NSManagedObject from a function with Xcode (ARC)

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I've a function which returns a NSManagedObject based on a predicate which seems to be memory leaking badly.

```
- (WordMap *)getWordMapForLetter:(NSString *)letter
{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"WordMap" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    WordMap *wordMap = Nil;

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"letter == %@", letter];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    if ([fetchedObjects count] > 0) {
        wordMap = (WordMap *)[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    return wordMap;
}
```

The problem looks to lie specifically with the following line as commenting it out stops the leak...

```
wordMap = (WordMap *)[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

I'm presuming the problem is that I'm returning a reference to an array item that was created within the scope of the function so therefore ARC cannot dispose of the array afterwards?

Is that correct or is the problem something else entirely? Regardless, I'm not at all sure how to go about stopping the leak- suggestions?

Comment: how do you know you get leaking memory issue? Do you use instrument to inspect those objects or you just guess?

Comment: No, not used instruments yet, but after putting a call to this function in a for loop I can see the memory usage going up steadily  (approximately 1.5MB each iteration) in the Debug Navigator until my test device eventually crashes.

Comment: Okay, following your suggestion I ran Instruments and the allocations are just continuing to increase memory usage. Problem is this never seems to level off or drop.